# iOS Simulate Single Tap Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building an Augmented Reality app that when it scan single image, I want it automatically play video.

Currently, I have to tap a button on the image to play the video using single tap gesture method.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       // handling code
       CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:eaglView];
       [eaglView handleTouchPoint:touchPoint];
    }
}
```

Now I want to simulate using `NSNotification`,when the scan finish and the video is ready to play

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(test) name:@"singleTap" object:nil];

-(void)test
{
    [self handleTap:nil];
}
```

But it will crash because I send it nil, how do I send the `sender.state` to the `handleTap` method since it expect `sender.state=UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't test the state of UITapGestureRecognizer, its a discrete gesture, it will have only one state (UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when the `handleTap` method called.

So you can do it like this:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
   // handling code
   CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:eaglView];
   [eaglView handleTouchPoint:touchPoint];
}
```

and simulate it:

```
-(void)test
{
    [self handleTap:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .h file:

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecog;`

and into .m file:
in **viewDidLoad**:

```
tapRecog = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[YourImage addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"singleTap" options:0 context:nil];
[YourImage addSubview:tapRecog];
```

and then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"singleTap"])
    {
        [self test];
    }
}
```

then modify the the test function:

```
-(void)test
{
    [self handleTap:tapRecog];
}
```